# Persisting error message about 'non-serializable' after using immer library

Tags: reactjs, redux, immer.js

I'm trying to update a react application state using redux the immer library, the problem is that even I still get a persisting warning message on console:

error:

```
A non-serializable value was detected in an action, in the path: `user.email`. Value: 
<input id="email" class="input_uawwg0" type="email" name="email" value="moez@gmail.com"> 
Take a look at the logic that dispatched this action:  
Object { type: "LOGIN", user: {…} }
 
(See https://redux.js.org/faq/actions#why-should-type-be-a-string-or-at-least-serializable-why-should-my-action-types-be-constants) 
(To allow non-serializable values see: https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/usage-guide#working-with-non-serializable-data)
```

below is hole logic behind:

```
// action
const login = (email, password) => {
  return {
    type: LOGIN,
    user: { email, password },
  }
};

// reducer
const actionsReducers = (state={}, action) => {
  switch(action.type) {
    case LOGIN:
      return produce(state, (draft) => {
        return { ...draft, ...action }
      }
    )
    default:
      return state;
}

const loginRequest = (email, password) => (dispatch) => {
  dispatch(login(email, password))
  return axios.get('http://localhost:8080/login-success.json')
    .then( response => dispatch(loginSuccess()))
    .catch( error => dispatch(loginFailure()))
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  login: (email, password) => dispatch(login(email, password)),
  logout: () => dispatch(logout()),
  displayNotificationDrawer: () =>  dispatch(displayNotificationDrawer()),
  hideNotificationDrawer: () => dispatch(hideNotificationDrawer()),
  loginRequest: () => dispatch(loginRequest(email, password))
});

// index
const root = createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));

const rootReducers = combineReducers({
  uiReducer,
  reducers,
})
const store = configureStore({reducer: uiReducer}, applyMiddleware(thunk))

root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <App />
    </Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

The action must update the store with a such object:

```
{ type: 'LOGIN', user: { email: 'test@test', password: 1234 } }
```

I called the props.loginRequest in App component where the isLoggedIn props is false:

```
class App extends Component {
  ...

  render() {
    const { 
      ...
      isLoggedIn,
      loginRequest
     } = this.props;
    return (
      <div>
        ...
        <div className={css(styles.app)}>
          {!isLoggedIn ? (
            <BodySection>
              <Login logIn={loginRequest} />
            </BodySection>
          ) : (
            <BodySection>
              <CourseList listCourses={listCourses} />
            </BodySection>
          )}
          <Footer />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  isLoggedIn: state.isUserLoggedIn,
  ...
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App);
```

Answer (score 1):

From the error message, it seems that you did not dispatch the user email 'test@test', but the HTML Input element instead.

Comment: No I did, check the code update please

Comment: You do not show how your component uses `props.loginRequest`.
Also, just to make sure as many tutorials still teach this are you aware that this is a very outdated (pre-2019) style of Redux? Modern Redux comes with immer included and is 1/4 of the code. No ACTION_TYPES or switch..case reducers.

Comment: yeah, I'm aware of the old redux style that uses switch with reducers, but I'm trying to add immer to remedy the non-serializable error, so I you've some recommendations for me about the redux new way to follow it'll be nice. The loginRequest will replace an old login method.

Comment: immer will not change anything about a serialization error here. Please show where you call `props.loginRequest` in the end in your component.

Comment: As for learning modern Redux, generally I'd recommend following the official tutorial :) https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-1-overview-concepts

Comment: And how does that `Login` component use the `logIn` prop?

Comment: using this method : handleLoginSubmit(e) {e.preventDefault(); this.props.logIn(this.state.email, this.state.password);}, and then pass the handleloginSubmit to form through a onSubmit action

Comment: And what is the code where you call `this.setState({email: ...})` ?

Comment: This was called inside other handlers one to check the change for email and one for password and these handlers are called inside the login form within the 'onchange' event, example of handlers:
handleChangeEmail(e) {
    this.setState({ email: e.target.value });
    this.setState((state) =>
      state.email !== "" && state.password !== ""
        ? { enableSubmit: true }
        : { enableSubmit: false }
    );
  }

Comment: Please log `this.state.email` at some points there. Again, judging from that error message, you do have a DOM element in there. That cannot turn up in the error message if it is not actually there - the logger will not suddenly make up the existance of a DOM element.

Comment: The log of this.state.email from email handler gives 'moez@gmail.com'

Comment: Why does your error message say `<input id="email" class="input_uawwg0" type="email" name="email" value="moez@gmail.com">` then? This value is definitely being dispatched, as `action.user.email`.

Comment: This is what I found weird, from my side

Comment: But it definitely *is* the value that is being passed into your `props.loginRequest` in the end, or it wouldn't end up there. So go through that stack and console.log it left and right.